# I want to auto rotate save as original file

Tags: java, image, image-processing, rotation, image-rotation

I want to auto rotate an image with java but I found error

> java.lang.NullPointerException at orientation =
>   exifIFD0Directory.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);

I don't know how to fix code rotate image save as original file

```
File imageFile = new File(inFilePath);
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);


Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imageFile);
ExifIFD0Directory exifIFD0Directory = metadata.getDirectory(ExifIFD0Directory.class);
JpegDirectory jpegDirectory = (JpegDirectory)metadata.getDirectory(JpegDirectory.class);

int orientation = 1;
try {
   orientation = exifIFD0Directory.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(orientation);
int width = jpegDirectory.getImageWidth();
int height = jpegDirectory.getImageHeight();

AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();

BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

switch (orientation) {
case 1:
   break;
case 2: // Flip X
   affineTransform.scale(-1.0, 1.0);
   affineTransform.translate(-width, 0);
   break;
case 3: // PI rotation
   affineTransform.translate(width, height);
   affineTransform.rotate(Math.PI);
   break;
case 4: // Flip Y
   affineTransform.scale(1.0, -1.0);
   affineTransform.translate(0, -height);
   break;
case 5: // - PI/2 and Flip X
   affineTransform.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
   affineTransform.scale(-1.0, 1.0);
   break;
case 6: // -PI/2 and -width
   affineTransform.translate(height, 0);
   affineTransform.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
   break;
case 7: // PI/2 and Flip
   affineTransform.scale(-1.0, 1.0);
   affineTransform.translate(-height, 0);
   affineTransform.translate(0, width);
   affineTransform.rotate(3 * Math.PI / 2);
   break;
case 8: // PI / 2
   affineTransform.translate(0, width);
   affineTransform.rotate(3 * Math.PI / 2);
   break;
default:
   break;
}

AffineTransformOp affineTransformOp = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
BufferedImage destinationImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getHeight(), originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getType());
destinationImage = affineTransformOp.filter(originalImage, destinationImage);
ImageIO.write(destinationImage, "jpg", new File(inFilePath));
```

Comment: Can you check if your `ExifIFD0Directory` is present and initialized correctly? Judging by your trace it seems to be `null` in your case.